# Sort bibliography automatically

Tags: bibliographies, sorting

I did not take care of the alphabetical order when I was adding references to the bibliography. So I have a big list with references not ordered. Is there a way to do it automatically? I use

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
 \def\cprime{$'$}
 \begin{thebibliography}{10}

 \bibitem{aza}
 A. Nash
 \newblock{\em Nice book }
 \newblock{ Springer}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: No. Without using BibTeX you must do it by hand.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

The basic answer must be "you have to do it by hand".

If you don't want to switch to BibTeX or biblatex/biber you have the following possibilities

1. Write your own script which does the sorting.
2. If you compile with LuaLaTeX you can write a lua function.
3. You can use the string functions of `expl3`. But you also have to program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to sort \bibitems in alphabetical order. Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/latex-bibitemstyler/, a nice little program that does this job like a charm.